# Android : edittext alert

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-alertdialog

**Is it possible to create an alert in the edittext?**

I've seen it in 2 apps with exactly the same style, so I understand it's a default view or property.

[image: the alert]

Comment: Have You checked setError method of EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to use https://github.com/vekexasia/android-edittext-validator

[image]

There are several values you can set to the test attribute:

1. regexp: for custom regexp
2. numeric: for an only numeric field
3. alpha: for an alpha only field
4. alphaNumeric:
5. personName: checks if the entered text is a person first or last name.
6. personFullName: checks if the entered value is a complete full name.
7. email: checks that the field is a valid email
8. creditCard: checks that the field contains a valid credit card using Luhn Algorithm
9. phone: checks that the field contains a valid phone number
10. domainName: checks that field contains a valid domain name ( always passes the test in API Level < 8 )
11. ipAddress: checks that the field contains a valid ip address
12. webUrl: checks that the field contains a valid url ( always passes the test in API Level < 8 )
13. date: checks that the field is a valid date/datetime format ( if customFormat is set, checks with customFormat )
14. nocheck: It does not check anything except the emptyness of the field.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [setError](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)) method. it is available from API Level one only.

```
editText.setError("Enter yor error message").
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:hint="@string/cont_num"
                android:inputType="phone"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

From the android design library

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an EditText widget one solution would be a RelativeLayout with a Auto complete TextView widget and an alert Icon of your choice set rightOf your AC TextView within the RL.

Then add a text change listener to your AC textview which is looking for your specific text input i.e. binary and if a breach is detected display warning and error icon?